# Can't grab images from Drupal Site with getElementsByIdTag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drupal

I was just trying to figure this out.  If I go to a website I built, I can open Chrome console I can and type in...

```
var grabImages = document.getElementsByIdTag("img");
console.log(grabImages);
```

This will print out all of the images tags.  However if I go to a Drupal website...say http://www.leeandassociatesaccountancy.com/ open up console and type the same thing I get an empty array result.  Upon viewing the source code I can see that the page does have img tags.  Not sure whats up.

I am basically doing this to get a list of images so I can check their alt attribute in chrome console to see if its set.  Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Document#getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName).

```
var grabImages = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
console.log(grabImages)
```

This works equally well:

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('img'))
```

Comment: Seems to return the same result as what I was using, and still nothing w/a Drupal built site

Comment: I visited your site, pasted in the exact code above, and got a massive array full of matches. Any other browser/environment information that might help explain that discrepancy?

Comment: Weird, gives me an empty array back.  I can go to any other website and type it in and get back an array though.  I think CMS / Drupal sites just don't work